# Display image data from json result type

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

This is my Get action method to get posts with their image:

```
       public JsonResult GetPosts()
        {
          var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   {
                       PostedByName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                       PostedByAvatar = _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(post.PostedBy),
                   });
          return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
```

and this is my GetFileData action method to retrieve the images from the database:

```
      public FileResult GetFileData(int fileId)
      {
        var file = db.Files.Single(x => x.FileId == fileId);
        return File(file.Content, file.ContentType);
       }
```

and this is the method which will generate url:

```
     private string _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(int? Id)
     {
        var avatarImage = db.Files.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ApplicationUserId == Id);
        if (avatarImage != null)
            return Url.Action("GetFileData", new { fileId = avatarImage.FileId });
        return String.Empty;
      }
```

and this is the view page to show the user name with their pic but i am not able to show pic:

```
       <div>
       <div id="ajaxDiv">
       </div>
       </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $.getJSON("/Post/GetPosts", null, function (data) {
     var div = $('#ajaxDiv');
     div.html("<br /> " + "Users received from server: " + "<br />");
     $.each(data, function (i, item)
     {
      printUser(div, item);
      });
     });
    });
 function printUser(div, item)
 {
     div.append("<br/>" + "UserName: " + item.PostedByName + "<br/>" + "Pic: " + item.PostedByAvatar);
   // I am stuck here on how to append image to this div or how to pass item.PostedByAvatar to this img src tag
     div.append("<img src= + item. />");
     <img src="@Url.Action("GetFileData", "Home", new { id = item.Id })" style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
   }
 </script>
```

the url which i am successfullly getting back is like this:

```
   /Post/GetFileData?fileId=2
```

how to resolve this ???

Comment: I have asked that how to insert that item.PostedByAvatar into img src attribute. i am getting correct path for every image saved in database. but dont know how to feed that url to img aatribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GetFileData` action the parameter name in `fileId`. But when you are setting the source of image you are using the parameter name `id` which should be `fileId` like below.

```
@Url.Action("GetFileData", "Home", new { fileId = item.Id })
```

**Update:** As you said this should work.

```
div.append('<img class=cssClassName src="' + item.PostedByAvatar +'"/>');
```

Comment: first thing i cannot insert that img tag in between bcoz of syntax error second thing url.action is server side code and item.Id is client side which even doesnot exist at that time

Comment: one more thing azim can u show how to insert style attribute in this img src attribute

Comment: dont worry i got it height and width too just like we do in normal way very much thnk u bro

Comment: you can use `css` `class` for that. write your `css` `class` in your `css` file and add the `class` name in `img` tag. see updated answer.